# How to force a longer `reboot` in Busybox v1.13.3?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, sh, busybox

`reboot` appears to make the root file system read-only *almost* immediately, causing a race condition with one of my processes which tries to write settings out to a file during its approx 1-2 second shutdown.

The result, intermittently, is an empty settings file as it's truncated but not filled back up in time.

I'm creating a workaround within the process in question itself, but I'd still like to add some sanity to the `reboot` command.

Now, I thought about aliasing `reboot` to `reboot -d 5` for the only account on the system, so that no-one will inadvertently perform this immediate shutdown, since `-d` introduces a delay:

```
[hostname /root]# reboot --help 2>&1 | grep Delay
        -d      Delay interval for rebooting
```

However, BusyBox v1.13.3 doesn't appear to support `alias` in its `sh` implementation:

```
[hostname /root]# alias reboot=reboot -d 5
-sh alias: not found
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The `alias` equivalent of a function could be achieved with something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
reboot() {
   cmd=/path/to/reboot
   $cmd -d 5
}
```

If that's not practical are you able to modify the BB reboot applet to have a default delay, or rename it and replace with a forwarding wrapper script?

Comment: 'fraid not - (a) turns out the delay option is useless anyway - [the applet simply does `sleep` before invoking Linux `reboot`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/init/halt.c#n123) (and doesn't do any signalling of its own), and (b) we would not be able to distribute an upgrade to the applet with [y]our software. The function approach could work, though... hmm.

Comment: Actually I guess (a) means that this whole question is moot now. :(

Comment: How about have the wrapper script or function perform any custom pre-shutdown signalling to any processes you desire, wait for (completion | specified delay | completion with specified timeout) then handover to busybox `reboot`?

Comment: Yeah I suppose injecting a bit of signalling to the specific processes I'm concerned about would do it. I wouldn't be comfortable signalling _everything_ myself, though, making this less of a catch-all workaround than I'd originally hoped. I'll give this a go; thanks :)

Comment: How about calling `kill(-1, SIGTERM)` (`<signal.h>`) before the delay; if run as root it gives all processes the '`SIGTERM`' heads up before the reboot applet does its own `SIGTERM - sleep(1) - SIGKILL` cycle

Comment: The `reboot` applet doesn't have such a cycle; it delegates to the `reboot` syscall to do all the signalling, _after_ the sleep. And as I said before I don't really wanna signal _everything_ (i.e. `-1`) as I can't be sure that this is equivalent to what `reboot` will do, and whether it may introduce unexpected consequences.

Comment: It seems to depend on the BB build config, but [`halt.c:151`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/init/halt.c#n151) will send `SIGTERM` to BB `init` if that's what you're using, and the handler for that (`halt_reboot_pwoff()`) calls [`run_shutdown_and_kill_processes()`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/init/init.c#n732), which performs the stated cycle; I _believe_ that cycle is standard for Linux.

Alternatively, might [`inittab`](http://linuxembedded.blogspot.co.uk/2006/11/understanding-busybox-inittab.html) be of any help?